# Typhoon support "Autowire" and "Scope" definition

Tags: objective-c, typhoon

If I compare Typhoon with one of the common IOC container spring in java i could not find two important freatures in the documentation.

How to annotate @autowired?
How to annotate @Scope? Especially distinglish between SCOPE_SINGLETON and SCOPE_PROTOTYPE.

More about spring here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-standard-annotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typhoon supports the prototype and singleton scopes along with two other scopes designed specifically for mobile and desktop applications.

In a server-side application, the server may be supporting any of the application's use-cases at a given time. Therefore it makes sense for those components to have the singleton scope. In a mobile application, while there *are* background services its more common to service one use case at a time. And there are memory, CPU and batter constraints.

Therefore the default scope with Typhoon is [TyphoonScopeObjectGraph](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Scopes#typhoonscopeobjectgraph-default), which means that references to other components while resolving eg a top-level controller will be shared. In this way an object graph can be loaded up and then disposed of when done.

There's also the following:

- [TyphoonScopeSingleton](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Scopes#typhoonscopesingleton)
- [TyphoonScopePrototype](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Scopes#typhoonscopeprototype)
- [TyphoonScopeWeakSingleton](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Scopes#typhoonscopeweaksingleton)

**Auto-wiring macros vs native style assembly:**

Unfortunately, Objective-C has only limited run-time support for "annotations" using macros. So the option was to use either a compile-time pre-processor, which has some drawbacks, or to work around the limitations and force it in using a quirky style. We decided that its best (for now) to use Macros only for simple convention-over-configuration cases.

For more control we strongly recommend using the native style of assembly. This allows the following:

- Modularize an application's configuration, so that the architecture tells a story.
- IDE code-completion and refactoring works without any additional plugins.
- Components can be resolved at runtime using the assembly interface, using Objective-C's AOP-like dynamism.

To set the scope using the native style:

```
- (id)rootController
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[RootViewController class] 
        configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition)
    {
        definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Ok i found now the related documentation: https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Autowiring & https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Scopes